# jquery sort & filter table

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-plugins

I have a problem with sorting and filtering html table.

[I use jQuery propdown Table Filter plugin](https://github.com/rbayliss/Dropdown-Table-Filter)
and it works perfectly well for me, but,

For now it looks like this:

[image]

But problem is i also need sort my table by values `(A-Z/Z-A)`, and I'm not strong via JQuery to re-write this plugin. It must look like this (add sorting options to select):

[image]

Can you give me direction, where I can look? I find a lot of jQuery plugins, but none did what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you perhaps thought of using JQuery Datatables??
They are really easy to use and you can sort your columns and filter the data (search box performs filter on all columns based on input text) by default.

http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: ... but if i dont find any option im use this one.

Comment: the coding language you are using does not matter... I have used the JQuery Datatables with .Net.

Comment: ops.. my mistake. I just thought it work with json or stuff like that. but looks like it match my  problem. Thanks again :)

Comment: pleasure... please make sure to vote and accept the answer if you are happy with the reply.

Answer (score 0):

For the Above sorting you can check ascii value of the character and then sort the character according to it.

For the NON English character, find the ascii value and then sort it.

For e.g.

```
"ABCDEF".charCodeAt(0)  // return 65
```

Same way for

```
"CÃNT".charCodeAt(1) // return 195
```

May this will help you